# Pulling data from a website address based on Excel values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem writing a macro for Excel VBA and couldn't find the exact answer to what I'm looking for.

I have the following URL:

> http://ratings.ambest.com/companyprofile.aspx?ambnum=2257

And I have a list of IDs in Column A of my Excel worksheet that I need to feed into the last part of that URL (changing the 2257 to, say, 73132 and 1996 in the example). Then, I need to fetch the credit rating on the resulting webpage, which would be following field:

> div id="MainContent_FSRandICR_AffilCodeDiv"

So, I need a macro that:

- Changes the last section of the URL based on the values on Column A
  of the worksheet.
- Pulls data from the field with the tag div id="MainContent_FSRandICR_AffilCodeDiv"
- Parses it into the same Excel worksheet into Column B, so for each ID I'd have its credit rating.
- Repeats until EOF

I managed to make a macro based on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7sZRcaaAVbg), but there are many issues with it, namely:

- I have to input each ID manually, whereas I want it to read from values in a given column automatically
- It fetches the value from the tag "td" that gives me more data than I want (I couldn't get it to work with div id).

  ```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
      If Target.Row = Range("Code").Row And _
      Target.Column = Range("Code").Column Then
      Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
      IE.Visible = True
      IE.navigate "http://ratings.ambest.com/companyprofile.aspx?ambnum=" & Range("Code").Value
      Do
          DoEvents
      Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
      Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
      Set Doc = IE.document
      Dim sDD As String
      sDD = Trim(Doc.getElementsByTagName("td")(1).innerText)
      IE.Quit
      Dim aDD As Variant
      aDD = Split(sDD, ",")
      Range("AMBest").Value = aDD(0)
      End If
  End Sub
  ```

Many thanks in advance for your help!

**UPDATE:** 
This is my current macro with help from YasserKhalil:

```
<pre><code>Sub Test()
Dim aDD, ie As New InternetExplorer, htmlDoc As HTMLDocument, sDD As String, r As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For r = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        ie.Visible = False
        ie.navigate "http://ratings.ambest.com/companyprofile.aspx?ambnum=" & Cells(r, 1).Value
        Do: DoEvents: Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Set htmlDoc = ie.document
        On Error GoTo Skipper
        sDD = Trim(htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("td")(1).innerText)
        aDD = Split(sDD, ",")
        Cells(r, 2).Value = aDD(0)
Skipper:
    Next r
ie.Quit
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub</pre></code>
```

It works, but every once in a while I get redirected to answer a captcha, that when solved it lets me into the URL originally set in the macro. I want the macro to display IE if it gets redirected so I can solve the captcha. Then be able to resumen the macro once it has reached the correct URL. Is this possible?

Comment: Login required to the website ..!

Comment: You're right, sorry about it. Would it help to create a generic user for you so you can use?

Comment: OK if it is free. Have you tested the code I posted? Give me your notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Target.Column = 1 Then
    Dim aDD, ie As New InternetExplorer, htmlDoc As HTMLDocument, sDD As String
    ie.Visible = False
    ie.navigate "http://ratings.ambest.com/companyprofile.aspx?ambnum=" & Target.Value
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Set htmlDoc = ie.document
    sDD = Trim(htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("td")(1).innerText)
    ie.Quit
    aDD = Split(sDD, ",")
    Target.Offset(, 1).Value = aDD(0)
End If
End Sub
```

And using loops

```
Sub Test()
Dim aDD, ie As New InternetExplorer, htmlDoc As HTMLDocument, sDD As String, r As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For r = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        ie.Visible = False
        ie.navigate "http://ratings.ambest.com/companyprofile.aspx?ambnum=" & Cells(r, 1).Value
        Do: DoEvents: Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Set htmlDoc = ie.document
        sDD = Trim(htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("td")(1).innerText)
        ie.Quit
        aDD = Split(sDD, ",")
        Cells(r, 2).Value = aDD(0)
    Next r
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: The first one works fine, thanks! I was trying the one with loops but it crashes since there is the "ie.Quit" command but it doesn't recall it while in the loop. (Currently trying to get an account set up)

Comment: Try putting the line `ie.Quit` after the loop.

Comment: It works! But I'm getting the following error upon reaching row 6: "Run-time error 9: Subscript out of range". EDIT: I figured out why. That row has an ID that returns an almost blank webpage, so the macro can't find the "td" tag. There would have to be an exception to the macro so it skips that ID on the sheet and move to the next.

Comment: May be using `On Error GoTo Skipper` and create a Skipper: before the Next loop statement.

Comment: That did it. Thank you again! One last thing (I'll update the question): every once in a while I get redirected to answer a captcha, when solved it lets me into the URL set in the macro. I want the macro to display IE if it gets redirected so I can solve the captcha. Then be able to resumen the macro once it has reached the correct URL. Is this possible?

Comment: @Mailo156 You could consider accepting this answer if original question is now answered to your satisfaction. Then post a new question with the captcha problem and what you have tried in order to solve it. I would however recommend strongly using explicit worksheet references and a proper page load wait  Do: DoEvents: Loop While ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or ie.Busy

Comment: OK, answer accepted and will post a new question. Thank you all!